# var $table = $('#table').DataTable(); is not defined

Tags: javascript, c#, model-view-controller, .net-core

there is my problem:

```
<table id="table"></table>

<script>
    var $table = $('#table').DataTable();
</script>
```

Order in _Layout.cshtml:

```
<script src="~/lib/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/lib/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/js/site.js" asp-append-version="true"></script>
<script src="~/lib/bootstrap-table/bootstrap-table.js"></script>
<script src="~/lib/TableExport/js/tableexport.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: I don't see anything that would import of `.DataTable()`. Is it supposed to be part of one of the other ones?

Answer (score 1):

All is ok, just copy

```
    <script src="~/lib/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="~/lib/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
    <script src="~/lib/bootstrap-table/bootstrap-table.js"></script>
```

to head of page and removed .DataTable()